# MistServer & ffmpeg video real-time processing

Tags: rtsp, rtmp, sdp

Ask about rtsp/rtmp/sdp!

An ongoing project aims to open a stream in Mistserver, send the video to ffmpeg, serve it from Mistserver, receive video from python/vlc via rtsp url and apply a recognition model.

It was planned to receive it from several computers, recognize it as each model, and derive a single result.

I ran into a problem here.

There seems to be a slight frame difference even when accessing Mistserver at the same time.

Because of these frame differences, it is difficult to make the recognition result into a single image.

**----question ---**

I wonder if it is possible to receive and use the unique ID, number, time, etc. of the frame when receiving video through rtsp/rtmp.

I wonder if it is correct that the sdp is included inside the rtsp, and if so, is there a unique frame number inside the sdp, or is it possible to output it?

This is sdp provided by Mistserver.

```
v=0
o=- 1692775182107 1 IN IP4 192.168.1
s=cam1
i=cam1
c=IN IP4 192.168.1
t=0 0
a=tool:MistServer/3.2.2
a=recvonly
a=type:broadcast
m=video 53135 RTP/AVP 97
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=cliprect:0,0,2160,3840
a=framesize:97 3840-2160
a=fmtp:97 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64E033;sprop-parameter-sets=Z2QAM6zZQDwAQ+myAAADAAIAAAMAeB4wYyw=,aOrvLA==
a=framerate:30
a=control:track0
```

It seems to have been wandering for days. Any help would be greatly appreciated!